How to Adjust Width, Height, and Additional Properties of a Circular Text Container in CSS?
I am working on a custom section in my HTML/CSS project where I have implemented a circular text effect. However, I am facing issues with adjusting the width and height of the container holding this circular text. Additionally, I want to apply other CSS properties to this container to better control its appearance and positioning. Below is the relevant part of my code:


.circular {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  /* Adjust the width here */
  height: 300px;
  /* Adjust the height here */
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circular span {
  font: 26px Monaco, MonoSpace;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}

.char1 {
  transform: rotate(12deg);
}

.char2 {
  transform: rotate(24deg);
}

.char3 {
  transform: rotate(36deg);
}

.char4 {
  transform: rotate(48deg);
}

.char5 {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.char6 {
  transform: rotate(72deg);
}

.char7 {
  transform: rotate(84deg);
}

.char8 {
  transform: rotate(96deg);
}

.char9 {
  transform: rotate(108deg);
}

.char10 {
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}

.char11 {
  transform: rotate(132deg);
}

.char12 {
  transform: rotate(144deg);
}

.char13 {
  transform: rotate(156deg);
}

.char14 {
  transform: rotate(168deg);
}

.char15 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.char16 {
  transform: rotate(192deg);
}

.char17 {
  transform: rotate(204deg);
}

.char18 {
  transform: rotate(216deg);
}

.char19 {
  transform: rotate(228deg);
}

.char20 {
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}

.char21 {
  transform: rotate(252deg);
}

.char22 {
  transform: rotate(264deg);
}

.char23 {
  transform: rotate(276deg);
}

.char24 {
  transform: rotate(288deg);
}

.char25 {
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}

.char26 {
  transform: rotate(312deg);
}

.char27 {
  transform: rotate(324deg);
}

.char28 {
  transform: rotate(336deg);
}

.char29 {
  transform: rotate(348deg);
}

.char30 {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.char31 {
  transform: rotate(372deg);
}

.char32 {
  transform: rotate(384deg);
}

.char33 {
  transform: rotate(396deg);
}

.char34 {
  transform: rotate(408deg);
}

.char35 {
  transform: rotate(420deg);
}

.char36 {
  transform: rotate(432deg);
}

.char37 {
  transform: rotate(444deg);
}

.char38 {
  transform: rotate(456deg);
}

.char39 {
  transform: rotate(468deg);
}
<h1 class="circular">
  <span class="char1">W</span>
  <span class="char2">e</span>
  <span class="char3">'</span>
  <span class="char4">r</span>
  <span class="char5">e</span>
  <span class="char6">t</span>
  <span class="char7">h</span>
  <span class="char8">e</span>
  <span class="char9">b</span>
  <span class="char10">e</span>
  <span class="char11">s</span>
  <span class="char12">t</span>
  <span class="char13">i</span>
  <span class="char14">e</span>
  <span class="char15">t</span>
  <span class="char16">h</span>
  <span class="char17">a</span>
  <span class="char18">t</span>
  <span class="char19">y</span>
  <span class="char20">o</span>
  <span class="char21">u</span>
  <span class="char22">c</span>
  <span class="char23">a</span>
  <span class="char24">n</span>
  <span class="char25">b</span>
  <span class="char26">e</span>
  <span class="char27">y</span>
  <span class="char28">o</span>
  <span class="char29">u</span>
  <span class="char30">r</span>
  <span class="char31">s</span>
  <span class="char32">e</span>
  <span class="char33">l</span>
  <span class="char34">f</span>
  <span class="char35">w</span>
  <span class="char36">i</span>
  <span class="char37">t</span>
  <span class="char38">h</span>
  <span class="char39">.</span>
</h1>



This is the my current section:

This is what it should be:

Currently, I have hardcoded the width and height of the .circular container to 300px, but I when I change it to 160px, nothing changed. Here are my questions:

How can I make the width and height of the .circular container 160px?
What is the best way to apply additional CSS properties to this container without affecting the circular text effect?
Are there any best practices for managing the positioning of the circular text spans within the container when the container size changes?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

It would honestly just be easier to have that part as an svg.

Yes, but I am not allowed to do it.

Any particular reason why?

You can also use javascript to place your letters in a circle shaped way. You won't have to write all these ' repeated lines'

@Mehdi, Can you show?

@gggggggggggggg yes sure pls check this link

@Mehdi, Thank you so much brother!

@gggggggggggggg you very welcome glad that it helped.

Here is a generic "circular text" element that can be used anywhere. Javascript required.


function initCircularText() {
  const circularTexts = document.getElementsByClassName('circular');
  for (let circularText of circularTexts) {
    const size = circularText.getAttribute('size');
    initOuterElement();
    initInnerElements();

    function initOuterElement() {
      circularText.style.width = size + 'px';
      circularText.style.height = size + 'px';
    }

    function initInnerElements() {
      const text = circularText.innerText;
      const characters = text.split('');

      const circularChars = characters
        .map(
          function(char, index) {
            const angle = index * 360 / characters.length - 180;
            const radius = size / Math.PI * 1.5;

            const style = `position: absolute;
              transform: rotate(${angle}deg) translateY(-${radius}px);
            `;
  
            return `<span style="${style}">${char}</span>`;
          }
        );

      circularText.innerHTML = circularChars.join('\n');
    }
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  initCircularText();
};
body {
  font-family: serif;
}

.circular {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
<h1>Our jewelry</h1>
<div class="circular" size="160"
     style="
            font-size: 11px;
            font-family: Monaco, monospace;
            ">
  &nbsp;&nbsp;We're the best that you can be yourself with.
</div>

<br>

<div class="circular" size="85" style="font-size: 11px; color: red;">more circular text</div>



First, define the following css to properly position circular text elements:
.circular {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

Next, call the following Javascript code on window.onload (or listen to "DOMContentLoaded") to initialize and position the characters inside the circular text.
function initCircularText() {
  const circularTexts = document.getElementsByClassName('circular');
  for (let circularText of circularTexts) {
    const size = circularText.getAttribute('size');
    initOuterElement();
    initInnerElements();

    function initOuterElement() {
      circularText.style.width = size + 'px';
      circularText.style.height = size + 'px';
    }

    function initInnerElements() {
      const text = circularText.innerText;
      const characters = text.split('');

      const circularChars = characters
        .map(
          function(char, index) {
            const angle = index * 360 / characters.length - 180;
            const radius = size / Math.PI * 1.5;

            const style = `position: absolute;
              transform: rotate(${angle}deg) translateY(-${radius}px);
            `;
  
            return `<span style="${style}">${char}</span>`;
          }
        );

      circularText.innerHTML = circularChars.join('\n');
    }
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  initCircularText();
};


This code will select all elements with class "circular" and apply a circular text effect to them.
Now, you can create circular text elements as follows:
<div class="circular" size="160"
  style="
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: Monaco, monospace;
  ">
  &nbsp;&nbsp;We're the best that you can be yourself with.
</div>

<div class="circular" size="85" style="font-size: 11px; color: red;">more circular text</div>

No need to have every character encapsulated with <span> tags, the initCircularText() function takes the inner text of each circular class element
and inserts transformed <span> elements to achieve the circular text effect.
If you have access to them, you might be able to use a CSS preprocessor like Sass to generate the appropriate CSS instead of using Javascript.


Now to answer your questions:

How can I make the width and height of the .circular container 160px?

Edit the size attribute of any element with the circular class.


What is the best way to apply additional CSS properties to this container without affecting the circular text effect?

You can apply any inline css styles to .circular elements, or add additional css classes for further styling.


Are there any best practices for managing the positioning of the circular text spans within the container when the container size changes?

Can you clarify this question with an example?



